# ngbdatepicker and ie 11

Tags: browser, backwards-compatibility

when using ngbdatepicker in angular 9 with IE 11, the datePicker won't open the date picker window.

```
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dpFrom" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" 
                        ngbDatepicker #f="ngbDatepicker">
                    <button type="button" class="icn">                            
                        <fa-icon class="text-primary fa-2x" [icon]="faCalendarAlt"   (click)="f.toggle()"></fa-icon>
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the those whom are interested i figured out the issue, when using ngbdatepicker and fontawsome icon in combination, you need to make sure that the click event of the ngbdatepicker stays with the date picker and not the fontawsome calendar icon click. other browsers do not complain bu IE does.